# Terraform how to import a CustomResourceDefinition to tell terraform state resource already exists (cert-manager)

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

When trying to redeploy a production cluster I have module for `cert-manager` see: https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/

When trying to run `terraform apply` I'm getting timeout errors. It appears that the `cert-manager` already exists in the cluster

```
➜ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces             
NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.100.0.1       <none>        443/TCP         47h
kube-system   cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.100.128.114   <none>        9402/TCP        20m
kube-system   cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.100.45.105    <none>        443/TCP         20m
kube-system   kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.100.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   2d20h
```

Normally I can run a `terraform import` on other AWS resources to tell Terraform that these resources already exist. How do I do that with a `CustomResourceDefinition`? What's the syntax for an import command?

### main.tf

```
# cert-manager required to issues certs within the Pulsar cluster
# https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/#installing-with-helm
module "cert-manager" {
  source = "../../../../../modules/helm"

  helm_release_name        = "cert-manager"
  helm_release_description = "TLS certificate manager required by Pulsar"
  helm_repo                = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  helm_chart_name          = "cert-manager"
  helm_chart_version       = "1.5.4"
  helm_create_namespace    = "true"
  helm_release_namespace   = "kube-system"
  helm_cleanup_on_fail     = "true"
  helm_set = {
    "installCRDs" = "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You state that you are attempting to redeploy an existing service, but then ask about importing a CRD. Also, is the CRD or service (depending upon which is desired) part of a Helm chart (since you tagged this Helm)? That would make the solution external to Terraform if you are also using the Helm provider.

Comment: Yes it's being installed via helm. In the instances where I have resources that the terraform state doesn't realize exist and is creating conflicts, I usually `terraform import` that resource to seemingly make the state files aware of these resources. The problem I'm facing with the `cert-manager` may be a different kind of problem.